# Using react components to render data controlled by third party library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React component that needs to consume data from a tree library built in vanilla JS. This library holds and manages data for all "tree nodes" and they're state - expanded/collapsed, selected, hidden, etc.

I'm unsure how to approach building react components because they ideally control their own state or use a store designed for use in react.

Here's a super simple example of data that might be loaded into the tree library.

```js
[{
    id: 1,
    text: 'Node 1'
}, {
    id: 2
    text: 'Node 2',
    state: {
        selected: true
    }
}]
```

It gets loaded into the tree lib via the constructor `new Tree(nodes);` and the tree lib provides a ton of methods to work with it: `tree.deselect(2)` and `tree.selected() // -> []`

I've toyed around with some basic components to render this example:

I start with `<TreeNodes nodes={tree.nodes()} />`

```
const TreeNodes = ({ nodes }: TreeNodesProps) => {
    return (<>{ nodes.map(node => <TreeNode key={node.id} node={node} />) }</>);
}

const TreeNode = ({ node }: TreeNodeProps) => {
    const onClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        node.toggleSelect();
    }

    return <div className={clsx({ selected: node.selected()})} onClick={onClick}>{node.text}</div>
}
```

The tree library fires events like `node.selected` to let me know when something has changed in the data.

My question is, what's the best/proper way to then sync my data to react components?

I was debating listening for all tree events and updating a state object in the root component but that feels wrong:

```js
const [nodes, setNodes] = useState(tree.nodes());

this.tree.on('node.selected', () => {
    setNodes(tree.nodes())
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more about `when something has changed in the data.` like what makes something change in the data?

Comment: If I were to use the pure-JS default dom library for this tree, it would render the nodes and allow a user to expand/collapse nodes, select nodes, hide or show them via an API, add and remove nodes via the API, edit node text in the browser, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't feel adding a listener is wrong as long as it works fine. Also I think you should wrap it up in a `useEffect` this way:

```
function MyApp() {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState(tree.nodes());

  useEffect(() => {
    tree.on("node.selected", () => {
      setNodes(tree.nodes());
    });
    return () => {/* remove listener here */}
  }, []);
}
```

You either have this solution or you will have to make all changes to the data by yourself.

Comment: I went ahead and tried this but the component never rerenders. Probably because the original lib is mutating a single object and there's no new state like react expects.

Comment: Did you try to console log here and there to know the behavior of your app?